# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Search#search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have installed ElasticSearch and I am unable to search when I use this:

```
<%= link_to genre_linker.genre, movie_genre_linker_path(@movie, genre_linker) %>
```

but the results are correctly displayed when I use this:

```
<%= link_to genre_linker.genre %>
```

So, since the search works, I am thinking the problem is in my syntax.

this is my route:

```
movie_genre_linker GET    /movies/:movie_id/genre_linkers/:id(.:format)         genre_linkers#show
```

this is the error message:
[image]

I am still sort of a noob, so any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

**movies_controller.rb**

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]


  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
  end


  def show
    @genre_linkers = GenreLinker.where(movie_id: @movie.id).order("created_at DESC")
     @common_linkers = CommonLinker.where(movie_id: @movie.id).order("created_at DESC")
    @theme_linkers = ThemeLinker.where(movie_id: @movie.id).order("created_at DESC")
     @location_linkers = LocationLinker.where(movie_id: @movie.id).order("created_at DESC")
  end


  def new
     @movie = current_user.movies.build
  end


  def edit
  end

  def create
    @movie = current_user.movies.build(movie_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.save
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.update(movie_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @movie.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to movies_url, notice: 'Movie was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    end

    def movie_params
       params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :description, :movie_length, :poster)
    end
end
```

**genre_linkers_controller.rb**

```
class GenreLinkersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_genre_linker, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :votes]
  before_action :set_movie
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @genre_linkers = GenreLinker.all
    respond_with(@genre_linkers)
  end

  def show
    @genre_linker = GenreLinker.find(params[:id])
  end

   def vote
      value = params[:type] == "up" ? 1 : -1
      @genre_linker = GenreLinker.find(params[:id])
     @genre_linker.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, value, current_user)
      redirect_to :back, notice: "thanks for the vote"
   end


  def new
    @genre_linker = GenreLinker.new
    respond_with(@genre_linker)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
     @genre_linker = GenreLinker.new(genre_linker_params)
     @genre_linker.user_id = current_user.id
     @genre_linker.movie_id = @movie.id

     if @genre_linker.save
        redirect_to @movie
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @genre_linker.update(genre_linker_params)
    respond_with(@genre_linker)
  end

  def destroy
    @genre_linker.destroy
    respond_with(@genre_linker)
  end

  private
    def set_genre_linker
      @genre_linker = GenreLinker.find(params[:id])
    end

   def set_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
   end

    def genre_linker_params
       params.require(:genre_linker).permit(:genre, :description)
    end
end
```

**search/search.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Search for" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<ul>
  <% @genre_linkers.each do |genre_linker| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to genre_linker.genre, movie_genre_linker_path(@movie, genre_linker) %>


    </li>

</ul
    <% end %>
```

**search_controller.rb**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
  if params[:q].nil?
    @genre_linkers = []
  else
    @genre_linkers = GenreLinker.search params[:q]
  end
end

end
```

Comment: Your controller can't find a route matching your parameters because it is missing a `:movie_id`. What's saved in your `@movie` instance variable?

Comment: I added the movies_controller, does that help?

Comment: Which view is the problematic link on?

Comment: The view is from **search/search.html.erb** I will add that code.

Comment: We also need to see the controller relating to that view.

Comment: I added the search_controller.

Comment: The view has no idea what `@movie` is supposed to be because it is never defined in the search action of your controller. Define it in the controller and then you can use the instance variable in your view.

Comment: Ok, so @movie needs to be defined in the search controller. That makes sense, however, I can't figure out how to write that out. If someone could help me out with how that looks, I would be really happy. In the mean time, I am hitting the books again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked: 
`<%= link_to genre_linker.genre, movie_path(genre_linker.movie.id) %>`